# Why is this snippet working properly, and not here?

Tags: yasnippet

I stumbled upon [this](http://tiborsimko.org/emacs-epydoc-snippets.html) feature for functions, and was eager to try it out.

However, I ran into an error message, after trying the snippet in python-mode:

```
[yas] elisp error: Symbol’s value as variable is void: text
```

From what I read on his blog, and seeing the others trying this snippet, it went propably without any problems for them. I couldn't figure out how I could bind any value to the text. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide more information. You should be able to find out where in the source code the `text` is that it is referring to. Post some of that code and it should be easy to help you. Looking at the page you cite, and searching for `text`, this part of the code seems problematic, as variable `text` in it indeed looks like a free variable: `(mapcar '(lambda (x) (split-string x "=")) (split-string text ","))`. Try setting `debug-on-error` to `t` and showing a backtrace.

Comment: I copied the source code of the yasnippet custom snippet `de`, as displayed on that page. The variable text is indeed not defined yet, as the backtrace told me. So it seems the author didn't delivered a working example of the source code. But I thought it was only me. You ran into an error too, I assume?

Comment: I didn't run into an error. I didn't try it. If you post the backtrace perhaps someone can help you further. That was the point.

Comment: When `debug-on-error` toggled to `t`, I didn't get any backtrace when the error occured. I got only that error message inside the yasnippet. Because the error occured when Yasnippet tried to interpret the snippet, and not Emacs, I guess.

Comment: I see. Maybe someone familiar with YAS will have a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text` variable is the old version of the contents of the field you're currently expanding/writing. I guess the name was too generic so in later versions of `yasnippet` it was replaced with the variable `yas-text` instead.

You should try replacing it with that and see if that helps.

Comment: Oh Xaldew, you're right. Thanks for sharing!